# How to prevent user for type special charecter in input box by PHP not by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with 3 input box that show in below:

```
echo '<form action="" name="frm_chg_pass" method="post">';
echo '<tr ><td class="td1">Dear user</td></tr>';
echo '<tr ><td class="td1"><p>'.$prs_name."  ".$prs_family.'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td class="td1">you will change your pass word please be careful for keeping it  </td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td class="td1">you dont allow for type these charecter: & > < / "'."'".' ; : )= ( ] [ # } { \ .</p></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td class="td1"><input type="text" id="id_pass_old" name="pass_old" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" required="required" autocomplete="off"     /></td><td class="td1"><p>Old Password</p></td>';
echo '<tr><td class="td1"><input type="password" id="id_pass_new" name="pass_new" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" required="required" autocomplete="off" /></td><td class="td1"><p>New Password</p></td>';
echo '<tr><td class="td1"><input type="password" id="id_pass_conf" name="pass_conf" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" required="required"  autocomplete="off"/></td><td class="td1"><p>Confirm new password</p></td>';
echo '<tr><td class="td1"><input type="submit" name="btn_change_pass" method="post" value="RegisterChang"/></td></tr>';
echo '</form>';
```

as you see I don't want user insert `& > < / "' ; : ) = ( ] [ # } { \` in input box and don't use JavaScript for check it. How can I prevent type these by PHP?

Comment: _don't use java for check it_ you mean javascript?

Comment: If you want to do it on client side (without request going to server) you will have to use javascript/jquery, but if you are okay for the user to enter the data and send to server then you can use PHP and take action according to the requirements. Since it's just about rejecting certain characters you should choose javascript/jquery

Comment: yes, because by disable java in browser, user can type wrong character.

Comment: Dear Nimesh, I don't want escape special character, because if use this method, escaped data maybe inserted into MySQL and when user want login he see this message "your password is wrong please try again"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do server-side validation in form's action. It should be something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['INPUTNAME'])) {
        $error .= 'Input data should be alpha numeric characters only.';
    }
}
```

Comment: ctype_alnum($_POST['INPUTNAME']) check entry of input  for non letter and number and allow  them but maybe user has a password such as "J@m@l" or has a non-Unicode password such as "جمال" all of them forbidden.

Comment: your help for this time help me, thanks, but for find exact solution i lock up and wait.

Comment: Aha! so I recommend you using preg_match function. Have you tried it?

Comment: preg_match: Searches subject for a match to the regular expression given in pattern. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_real_escape_string, you can find out the information on its usage at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php. It is built right into the MySQL extension and is designed specifically for escaping dangerous characters out of a query string prior to passing the query to the database server. Ideal solution is to use escape special character for handling the form data within the PHP logic and use mysqli_real_escape_string for handling the form data in the query string prior to passing it to the database server. As for the issue of the escaped data being passed to MySQL as a password, as long as you use the escape function during all database procedures, especially saving a password as well as verifying the password then the passwords will match even if the user is using special characters in their password, the only difference is that while the user may type in a hash or ampersand as part of their password the database safe escaped string would be used when the password is saved and each time the user types in the password and it is checked against the database it will match as long as the user supplied strings are escaped the same way.

Comment: As a side note input verification should always be done on the server even if client side verification is used. I use jQuery to validate all form data prior to the form being submitted to provide faster feedback to the user of the data validity but I also check the data to make sure it is safe and what is expected on the server side as well specifically because client side verification is so easy to bypass.

Comment: How do you attention a special character inserted or write on input box by PHP? i know that some function for escape special character but they prevent from insert to DB and remaining string with out special character inserted.

Comment: An alternate solution if the only concern for this is for passwords would be to apply cryptography such as bcrypt or md5 to the string before passing it to the database, would both provide password security as well as dealing with the special characters problem. the only other solution I can think of off the top of my head would be to look at php's str_replace function which would let you replace a special character with a database friendly character strings, all of these are options but depend on your specific usage case.

Comment: In first time each password of user equal to Account number due i should check each password with query in db, so i want check every pass with special character that maybe harmful or cause injection in my query. with pattern in input tag we can limit some entry but isn't usual.